# How to discover dynamically loaded modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was attempting to use `importlib.util` I ended up only importing `importlib`

```
$ python3.6
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.util
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

Since I knew there was an `importlib.util` I then imported the full module name

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> importlib.util
<module 'importlib.util' from     '/Users/alexlord/.virtualenvs/python3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/util.py'>
```

This looks like a dynamic module that's only loaded if you directly import it.

This got me wondeirng, how does one discover these dynamically loaded modules? Is there a programmatic way to discover them or do I just need to enumerate the source code?

Comment: `importlib` is a package. Submodules of packages are only loaded once something explicitly imports them (though that explicit import might be somewhere you never see it, depending on the package and submodule.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, packages do not import modules (or sub-packages).

So:

```
import importlib
```

does not import the module util.

But the developper can choose to do it for you.

For instance:

```
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> os.path.pathsep
':'
```

To understand everything about modules and packages, there is an [excellent tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Note: you can also meet "namespace packages". See [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for details.

**EDIT**

To find sub-modules you can use `pkg_resources.resource_listdir()`:

```
import pkg_resources

l = [m for m in pkg_resources.resource_listdir('importlib', '.')
     if m.endswith('.py') and not m.startswith('_')]
```

You get:

```
['abc.py', 'machinery.py', 'util.py']
```

See [Basic Resource Access](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) in the documentation.

**EDIT 2**

Another way to discover subpackages or submodules is to use [pkgutil.walk_packages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html). It is probably the best solution.

For instance:

```
import pkgutil
import importlib

for i in pkgutil.walk_packages(importlib.__path__):
    print(i)
```

You get:

```
(FileFinder('/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84CF9501-45D6-43E0-9319-886F5DE85176/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/importlib'), '_bootstrap', False)
(FileFinder('/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84CF9501-45D6-43E0-9319-886F5DE85176/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/importlib'), '_bootstrap_external', False)
(FileFinder('/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84CF9501-45D6-43E0-9319-886F5DE85176/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/importlib'), 'abc', False)
(FileFinder('/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84CF9501-45D6-43E0-9319-886F5DE85176/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/importlib'), 'machinery', False)
(FileFinder('/var/containers/Bundle/Application/84CF9501-45D6-43E0-9319-886F5DE85176/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/importlib'), 'util', False)
```

Comment: `os.path` is a bad example, since `os` isn't actually a package. `os` directly messes with `sys.modules` to make `os.path` behave a little like a package submodule.

Comment: Well, I don't know this detail. Any other example in the standard lib?

Comment: I think `os` is the only module in the standard library that does the weird things it does. As for examples of packages, `collections` is a package in Python 3, with `collections.abc` as a submodule. There's also `multiprocessing` and a few others.

Comment: So this explains why this behavior happens but my question was more about if there's a mechanism to discover sub-packages or modules other then crawling a file system.

Comment: To find the subpackages you need to crawl the file system anyway. This is how they are found. A good practice can be using `pkg_resources`.

Comment: Cool, this answers my question. The walk packages way of doing things is nicer but ultimately it's a file system walk. It doesn't bother me that that is the answer it just seems like Python (a language with so much introspection) would probably have a more automated way of introspecting.